# What is the official/formal term for a "population share"?

Tags: terminology, percentage

I am not a statistician but I plan on using the appropriate term to indicate the "percentage share" of a city's population to the total population of its state.

Example:

```
City population = 1,384
State population = 15,437

(1,384/15,437)*100 = 8.97%
```

City population of 1,384 accounts for 8.97% of the state population of 15,437. What is the term for 8.97%?

Answer (score 1):

A percentage. I don't believe there's any more specific term than that. You could call it a "proportion", but when a number is called a proportion, it's typically expressed out of 1 rather than out of 100%.

Comment: In one census official website, the term "percent to population" was used. Some Wikipedia geographic articles I have seen used "population share" and "population percentage". If I use any of these, which might be the better term to use?

Comment: @JAT86 I think "population share" is clearest, or more verbosely "share of the population".